# MSG BOX prob in c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm a Beginner in c# so It's not encouraging  to me see you voting down on my basic question...

This is a button to show in a message Box the result  of my select from my BD.

I get  errors : Argument '2': cannot convert from 'object' to 'string',
Argument '3': cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'

Thank's for helping me!

```
  private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "Select id_Client,numéro_Teléphone from Clients";

        SqlDataReader thisreader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (thisreader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(thisreader["id_Client"],thisreader["numéro_Teléphone"]);
        }
        thisreader.Close();
        thisConnection.Close();



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
MessageBox.Show(thisreader["id_Client"].ToString() + " " +  
       thisreader["numéro_Teléphone"].ToString());
```

Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) doc for more details.

EDIT:

Use System.Text.StringBuilder to append strings.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb=new System.Text.StringBuilder();

while (thisreader.Read())
 {
    sb.Append("\n" +  thisreader["id_Client"].ToString() + " " +  
           thisreader["numéro_Teléphone"].ToString());   

   //or
   //sb.Append(string.Format("\n{0} {1}",thisreader["id_Client"],thisreader["numéro_Teléphone"]));      
 }
 MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication5.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method 'textBox1_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication5.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Edit your post and paste some code there so I can tell you where a problem is.

Comment: Select textBox1 control, open property window, select event - TextChanged and remove it by hand.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your help, I learned a lot from you! All the books about ado.net are in console mode.... I'm Beginner in c#.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things I would add here.

I don't think the call

```
thisreader["id_Client"].ToString()
```

is DBNull safe, meaning if the actual value back from the database is NULL this might cause a problem.

Secondly, your connection to the database server will not be closed until a user has clicked through all of the MessageBoxes. That might not be expected behavior. I almost always use a DataTable and a SqlDataAdapter to fill it, that way I know I have all my data back from the server and my connection has been closed so I am not using up extra resources on the server.

Also another things, since you are new to C# your

```
thisreader.Close();
thisConnection.Close();
```

might not get executed, you need to either do a

> try / catch / finally

or a

> using()

statement. Just giving you some best practices stuff to think about.